# GPS: loc.getLatitude/Longitude always results in 0.0

Tags: android, get, gps

I used [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39239/0/page/1) tutorial to write my app. I use the DDMS Location Manager to change my location virtually.

Unfortunally I always get a location of 0.0 for long and lat. Even if I switch them later in the prog with locationchanged-method I get 0.0.

Code is this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //---use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations---
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener); 

    Location lastLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation("gps");

    curLocation = "Standort: \nLatitude: " + lastLoc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + lastLoc.getLongitude();

    upperText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    upperText.setText(curLocation);
}
```

and

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
    {
        if (loc != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + 
                " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (loc != null) 
        {
            upperText.setText(curLocation + "\n\nStandort: \nLatitude: " + loc.getLatitude() 
                    + "\nLongitude: " + loc.getLongitude());
        }
    }
```

Something's missing, but I don't know what... :/

I'd be really pleased if anyone could help =)!

Comment: Are you passing latitude/longitude like that : 48.020203 or 48,020203?

Comment: In the DDMS I write 48.020203. So a point. I used the default input of the Location Manager which didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

go to maps default application and allow user to allow latitude and longitude option .In our application when the GPS signal blinks and when it stops we will get the latitude and longitude.It worked for me